# Ubuntu 18.10 (not new install) snap applications load but don't open

Tags: snap, 18.10, startup-applications

Applications like phpstorm, skype, slack etc won't open. Even system monitor, calculator etc don't open as well. I can open terminal, browsers, software & updates. How to fix this? Tried rebooting many times.

```
snap list:

Name                  Version         Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
core                  16-2.36.3       6130  stable    canonical✓  core
gnome-3-26-1604       3.26.0          74    stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-calculator      3.30.1          260   stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-characters      3.30.0          139   stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-logs            3.30.0          45    stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-system-monitor  3.30.0          57    stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes     0.1-4-g88bc1b2  818   stable/…  canonical✓  -
phpstorm              2018.3.1        74    stable    jetbrains✓  classic
skype                 8.34.0.78       66    stable    skype✓      classic
slack                 3.3.3           9     stable    slack✓      classic
```

When trying to launch from terminal eg. `skype` output is

```
/var not root-owned 1000:0
```

Trying to launch from ubuntu software nothing happens as well from statup.

I removed `gnome-system-monitor` snap and reinstalled using `apt` by running the following in Terminal:

```
snap remove gnome-system-monitor
sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor
```

Now system monitor starts.

Comment: How did you add them to startup applications? Sounds like you're having the issue with only snap applications.

Comment: I installed them with ubuntu software application

Comment: edited upthere with output of snap list

Comment: `snap remove gnome-system-monitor
sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor` now system monitor starts. Will try with other apps

Comment: That confirms my suspicion, all the problematic applications you mentioned are snap applications. Please [edit] your question and clarify what exactly is your problem. Are they *not starting automatically* after system startup (as the [startup-applications] tag suggests)? Can you launch them manually? Else can you launch them from Terminal? If not, what kind of error messages do they show?

Comment: Trying to launch from terminal eg. skype output is */var not root-owned 1000:0* . Trying to launch from ubuntu software nothing happens aswell from statup.